# azure storage blob file dont exist on local machine

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-web-app-service, azure-blob-storage

I am following the steps from edx course and when I am running a command from azure storage blob to upload files as instructed in the course I am getting the error. Where do on the local machine I have to create the demofile.

ping www.microsoft.com > demofile.txt what is that doing ?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I was able to upload the file, when I moved it from system32 folder to another folder and change the cli directory to that path.

Comment: lets say I am system32 folder and file is another path, how would give that local path in the command

Comment: Do you try to use full path?

Comment: That's was the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was not using the full path in the command